# Subtract two field w/ time data type in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to insert and update record on my mysql table. I want to update the is_logout field to 1 if the difference of two field w/ time data type is more than 15 minutes.

I have time_start and time_latest.

a query will look like this:

```
UPDATE table set is_logout = 1 WHERE (time_latest - time_start) > 15
```

How to do this?

Comment: why to have is_logout field at all? any reason for the denormalization?

Comment: when my visitor open a page it set the time_start and is_logout to zero (0). when the visitor close the page it update the field is_logout to 1. if it happens that my script cannot detect the unload event i will consider the visitor as not active then changing the is_logout from 0 to 1.

Comment: you can always tell it without such field, by just selecting last login time

Comment: my point is to update is_logout if the difference of the two time is more than 15. time_latest should be a current time.

Comment: i can't get you. all i need is a function to calculate current time - start time on my sql statement.

Comment: @user1034801 I upvoted your question which was downvoted earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Use below query:

`UPDATE table set is_logout = 1 WHERE (NOW() - time_start) > 15`

`NOW()` will give you current time. I believe you have `time_start` in your database.

Comment: thank you very much. however when i test it to include it in fields so I can see the value of its difference the result is not correct. I added a time_format to include only time as: TIME_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  '%H:%i:%s' ) - time_start. if current time is 02:48:43 and time_start is 02:35:52 the result is -23538. suppose to be the result is 14 minutes.

Comment: i modified it w/ this: MINUTE( TIMEDIFF( TIME_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  '%H:%i:%s' ) , time_start ) ). and it works now. thanks for the hint.